# Apache Ant -- use command line argument for target

Tags: java, ant

How can I call a target based on the command line argument?  For example, I want to have

`ant -Dbits=32 test` call `<target name="test-32">` and

`ant -Dbits=64 test` call `<target name="test-64">`

I tried this:

```
<target name="test-32">
...
</target>

<target name="test-64">
...
</target>

<target name="test" depends="test-${bits}">
```

But when I run the script with:

```
ant -Dbits=32 test
```

I get the following error:

> Target "test-${bits}" does not exist in the project

Comment: Why not just `ant test_32` and `ant test_64` ?

Comment: Code duplication.  I want to factor out the common code.  The only difference between the two targets is a single compiler flag.

Comment: If its just one different flag you could set things up using a `<condition>` on the value of "${bits}" in the test target itself rather than having separate 32 and 64 targets.

Comment: @IanRoberts Can you show how to use the `<condition>` variable in the way you describe?  I am a bit new to ant and cannot figure it out from the documentation.

Comment: I've edited my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a trick like

```
<target name="test.type">
  <property name="run.test${bits}" value="yes"/>
</target>

<target name="test32" if="run.test32">
  ...
</target>

<target name="test64" if="run.test64">
  ...
</target>

<target name="test" depends="test.type, test32, test64"/>
```

Alternatively, if, as you suggest in the comments, the difference between the 32 and 64 bit cases is just a single property value (a compiler flag) then you could set that property with `<condition>`, for example

```
<target name="test">
  <!-- value="..." is the value to use if the condition is true,
       else="..." is the value to use if the condition is false -->
  <condition property="compiler.arch" value="x86_64" else="i386">
    <equals arg1="${bits}" args2="64" />
  </condition>

  <!-- use ${compiler.arch} here -->
</target>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
<target name="test">
    <antcall target="test-${bits}"/>
</target>
```

Comment: The issue with antcall is that it calls the target in a new "project", so property settings made by the called target don't propagate back to the caller.  You need to use something like the `antcallback` task from `ant-contrib` if you need to copy things back from the called task to the caller.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks for pointing that out, I wasn't aware of this. But depending on the responsibilities of the caller and the called task, this may or may not be a problem. For example - if the caller is only used to select the actual task, and all the work happens inside the called task, it shouldn't matter that properties don't propagate back. YMMV.